# How to drop user in postgres if it has depending objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Database idd owner is role `idd_owner`.

Database has 2 data schemas: `public` and `firma1`. 
User may have directly or indirectly assigned rights in this database and objects.
User is not owner of any object. It has only granted rights.

How to drops such user ?

I tried

```
revoke all on all tables in schema public,firma1 from "vantaa" cascade;
revoke all on all sequences in schema public,firma1 from "vantaa" cascade;
revoke all on database idd from "vantaa" cascade;
revoke all on all functions in schema public,firma1 from "vantaa" cascade;
revoke all on schema public,firma1 from "vantaa" cascade;
revoke idd_owner from "vantaa" cascade;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public,firma1 revoke all ON TABLES from "vantaa";
DROP ROLE if exists "vantaa"
```

but got error

```
role "vantaa" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for schema public
DROP ROLE if exists "vantaa"
```

How to fix this so that user can dropped ?

How to create sql or plpgsql method which takes user name as parameter and drops this user in all cases without dropping data ?

Using Postgres 9.1+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL - how to quickly drop a user with existing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023583/postgresql-how-to-quickly-drop-a-user-with-existing-privileges)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before dropping the user you can run :

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY vantaa TO <newuser>
```

you could just reassign to postgres if you don't know who to reassign that to ...

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY vantaa TO postgres;
```

Comment: I tried but got error `permission denied to reassign objects` . User which runs this command is not superuser. I can add some rights to user  who invokes this command if this helps. How to fix ?

Comment: I also tried `reassign owned by vantaa to idd_owner` but got same error.

Comment: I ran reassign command under user postgres. After that drop user still causes the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Your reassignment can fail.
When you reassign to a new user/role
 - you do it on the currently selected database
 - the current user must belong to the 'from' role and 'to' (grant them and revoke them after)

Excerpt of a shell script of mine (a few things omitted)

```
# The DROP USER operation will fail if this user is the owner of an existing schema, table, index...
# The user creating a resource owns it. It should transfer the ownership to the role
# When reassigning, the current user needs to have the <<roles>> associated to BY and TO to execute the command.
GRANT $_roleservice TO $_superuser;                       
GRANT $_account TO $_superuser;                                                                
REASSIGN OWNED BY $_account TO $_roleservice;            
# dropping the user removes it from the current user list of roles/users
DROP USER $_account;  
REVOKE $_roleservice FROM $_superuser;
```