# Cannot drop PostgreSQL role. Error: `cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it`

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles, ddl, database-administration

I was trying to delete PostgreSQL user:

```
DROP USER ryan;
```

I received this error:

> ```
> Error in query:
> ERROR: role "ryan" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
> DETAIL: privileges for database mydatabase
> ```

I looked for a solution from these threads:

- [PostgreSQL - how to quickly drop a user with existing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023583/postgresql-how-to-quickly-drop-a-user-with-existing-privileges)
- [How to drop user in postgres if it has depending objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988702/how-to-drop-user-in-postgres-if-it-has-depending-objects)

Still have the same error.

This happens after I grant all permission to user "ryan" with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabase ON SCHEMA public TO ryan;
```

Answer (score 206, accepted):

[`DROP USER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropuser.html) (or [`DROP ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droprole.html), same thing) cannot proceed while the role still owns anything or has any granted privileges on other objects.

Get rid of all privileges with **`DROP OWNED`** *(which isn't too obvious from the wording)*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html)

> [...] Any privileges granted to the given roles on objects in the current
> database and on shared objects (databases, tablespaces) will also be revoked.

So the reliable sequence of commands to drop a role is:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY ryan TO postgres;  -- or some other trusted role
DROP OWNED BY ryan;
```

Run both commands in **every database of the same cluster** where the role owns anything or has any privileges!
And finally:

```
DROP USER ryan;
```

- [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html) changes ownership for all objects currently owned by the role.
- [`DROP OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html) then only revokes privileges (ownerships out of the way).

Alternatively, you can skip `REASSIGN OWNED`. Then `DROP OWNED` will (also) drop all objects owned by the user. (Are you sure?!)

Related:

- [Drop a role with privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997897/drop-a-role-with-privileges/47998115#47998115) <sub>(with a function to generate commands for all relevant DBs)</sub>
- [Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155356/3684)

Comment: I get this error even when the user doesn't own anything. It merely has GRANT permission on a few tables owned by another user. Therefore this solution won't work because there's nothing to reassign.

Comment: @Cerin: Did you to see the quoted sentence about `DROP OWNED`?

Comment: Thank you, one question though -- why you started with `REASSIGN`?

Comment: @astrowalker: I added more explanation above.

Comment: I get "[42501] ERROR: permission denied to reassign objects" error thought use admin account to execute query.

Comment: @Tomas: Is the "admin account" actually a superuser? (`SHOW IS_SUPERUSER`; while connected as the role.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, thanks! Could you take this comment
`-- repeat both in ALL databases where the role owns anything or has any privileges!`
out of code block so it would appear more like instruction, not comment about the command? I spent few minutes wondering&experimenting before i noticed it ;)

Comment: @atsu85: I clarified a bit.

Comment: Neither reassigning OWNED nor dropping them worked for me. Still got the same error when running from a superuser.

Comment: @rovyko: It's not "either / or", it's `REASSIGN OWNED ...` *and* `DROP OWNED ...` in every involved database of the same cluster before you can reliably `DROP ROLE ...`

Comment: For those of you who stumble onto this answer when working with Google Cloud SQL, note that it is not currently possible for `REASSIGN OWNER` to work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52244674/288341 and https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#superuser_restrictions

Comment: This doesn't work with PostgreSQL on RDS, even from the master login.

Answer (score 36):

What worked for me was to follow these steps:

1. Connecting to the database

```
\c mydatabase
```

2. Reassigning ownership

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY ryan TO <newuser>;
```

Or/and just deleting the object

```
DROP OWNED BY ryan;
```

3. Executing `REVOKE PRIVILEGES`

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM ryan;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM ryan;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM ryan;
```

4. Dropping the user

```
DROP USER ryan;
```

PS: You might not need to execute both Step 2 and 3, just one of the two steps might be usually enough.

Comment: Use `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db_name FROM role_name;` and `REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM role_name;` to revoke connect and usage privileges respectively. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28849656/1647238)

Comment: Above comment works!

Comment: I get: ```mydatabase=> REASSIGN OWNED BY ryan TO rian;
ERROR:  permission denied to reassign objects```

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me on RDS Postgres 13:

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <my_db> FROM <my_user>;`

I also had a similar error where the role was owner for tables so it couldn't be dropped, had to re-assign table owner with:

`ALTER TABLE <my_table> OWNER TO <trusted_role>;`

Doing a REASSIGN like this didn't work for me on RDS because AWS doesn't give you full superuser to your master user:
`REASSIGN OWNED BY <olduser> TO <newuser>;`

Comment: I had an issue exactly with this stack. My solution is here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301785/224108

Answer (score 9):

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA "public" FROM "<user>";
```

Worked for me.

Comment: IMHO this is just a part of Andrews answer.

Comment: @ahuemmer `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE` is not the same as `REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA`

Comment: I'm aware of that, nevertheless the effect would be the same. It also occurs in Samuel Anyaeles answer the way you do it, yours is only a shorter form.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to recreate `template1` database and then drop some role:

```
$ psql -U postgres postgres
postgres=# update pg_database set datistemplate = false where datname='template1';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# drop database template1;
DROP DATABASE
postgres=# create database template1 template=template0;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# update pg_database set datistemplate = true where datname='template1';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# DROP ROLE test;
DROP ROLE
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who use AWS Postgresql RDS, you may try following

1. login to postgres user, then grant owner

```
postgres=> GRANT target_user to old_user;
GRANT ROLE
```

2. Login to target db using user that would like to remove(old_user), then reassign

```
target_db=> REASSIGN OWNED BY old_user TO target_user;
REASSIGN OWNED
```

3. Login back to postgres user, revoke all privileges then drop user

```
postgres=> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE target_db FROM old_user;
REVOKE
postgres=> DROP USER old_user;
DROP ROLE
```

Ref. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-drop-user-role/