# GCP SQL Postgres problem with privileges : can't run a query with postgres user with generated symfony db

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am struggling to solve this problem with Google Cloud Platform's Cloud SQL component. My tech stack consists of hosting my application in a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) deployment, using the Cloud SQL proxy sidecar to connect to the database within the pods. The backend is a Symfony project.

I follow these steps to create and populate the database (without success):

1. Create Cloud SQL Postgres instance
2. Add proxy to k8s container to connect to the Cloud SQL instance with all credentials, as described in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine)
3. Enter my Symfony (`phpfpm`) pod and run the command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to update the schema. The queries are executed in the database, so the schema is created and so on.
4. I try to open the database from the SQL console connection within GCP with the `postgres` user and try to execute a simple `select * from foo;` query. The response is `Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied for relation`

How can I query the data in the database with the `postgres` user?

**EDIT :**

I have this situation about users :

```
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |           Member of           
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------
 acando14          | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser,proxyuser}
 cloudsqladmin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 cloudsqlagent     | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqlreplica   | Replication                                                | {}
 cloudsqlsuperuser | Create role, Create DB                                     | {}
 postgres          | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser,acando14}
 proxyuser         | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
```

And I have this situation in the tables :

```
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | article         | table | acando14
```

If I use postgres user logged in my db `symfony` works :

```
symfony => select * from article;
 id | model_id | code | size 
----+----------+------+------
(0 rows)
```

But if I use the server to execute the code the response is :

> SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR: permission denied
>   for relation employee at PDOException(code: 42501): SQLSTATE[42501]:
>   Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR: permission denied for relation .. at

And another problem is that I didn't generate all the tables with the command but I have to generate it executing all the queries, so strange...

Thank you, regards

Comment: As what user does the service hosted in k8s connect to the database?

Comment: With proxyuser...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default `postgres` user in Google Cloud Platform's (GCP) Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) is not a superuser of the instance ([GCP docs link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users)):

> When you create a new Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL instance... the `postgres` user is part of the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role, and has the following attributes (privileges): `CREATEROLE`, `CREATEDB`, and `LOGIN`. It does not have the `SUPERUSER` or `REPLICATION` attributes.

The superuser attribute grants a user the ability to bypass all permissions checks and, accordingly, it can go anywhere in the database instance to read data from any database ([PostgreSQL docs link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-attributes.html)):

> A database superuser bypasses all permission checks, except the right to log in.

In a typical PostgreSQL deployment outside GCP, the `postgres` user is indeed a superuser. This deviation in Cloud SQL breaks with the normal convention expected of Postgres that the `postgres` user can always access and mutate any object in the cluster by virtue of those superuser rights.

Without this privilege, you will need to be more careful about the roles used when creating database objects and the role used when attempting to access them, either interactively at the Postgres shell or programmatically in your application.

I assume you are using a separate, dedicated user for your k8s deployment to connect to the database, rather than the `postgres` user. By default, that user's role will own the objects created by the schema population operation. Per the [`GRANT` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html), this owner will by default have the full suite of privileges over the object:

> If the “Access privileges” column is empty for a given object, it means the object has default privileges (that is, its privileges column is null). Default privileges always include all privileges for the owner...

---

## Alternatives

- (Recommended) Create a dedicated role which can be shared between the `postgres` user and whatever other user(s) you log into the database with to populate its schema.

  Configure the operation which populates the database objects in the schema creation operation to set its role prior to creating the objects to this shared role, such that all users have the ability to access, manage and view these objects. By default, new roles have the `INHERIT` attribute set, which means attempts to access the objects created by the role will succeed for members of the role in future.

  For example, you could use the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role for this purpose, of which all users created in the console and the `postgres` built-in are automatically members. However, I would recommend creating a custom role for the purpose:

  ```
  CREATE ROLE symfonyapp;
  GRANT symfonyapp TO postgres;
  GRANT symfonyapp TO <your_k8s_application_user>;
  ```

  Later, when creating database objects, ensure you assume the `symfonyapp` role before doing so. At the console, run:

  ```
  SET ROLE symfonyapp;
  ```

  when logged in as a user to which the `symfonyapp` role has been granted. You should review the documentation of the libraries you are using to ascertain how to set the role when connecting to the database programmatically.
- Create a role as above, and assign it to the `postgres` user. Additionally, give the role the `LOGIN` attribute and set a password, which permits you to log into the database instance using the role name and a password directly. In this case, the `postgres` user inherits privileges of the role (such as objects it owns), and the ability to log in directly obviates the need to call `SET ROLE` on first connection.
- For objects already created, you can adjust their ownership to your custom role using the command `ALTER <TYPE> <name> OWNER TO symfonyapp`; for example:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE mytable OWNER TO symfonyapp;
  ```

It is not possible to directly grant the `SUPERUSER` role attribute to the `postgres` user, as you do not have access to a user with `SUPERUSER` privileges to do so! (Only superusers can make other users superusers.) The Google Cloud SQL for Postgres [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#differences-pg) notes a specific exclusion of support for any features which require superuser privileges, so this route is not available to you. The only superuser is the `cloudsqladmin` user, created by default and used by Google to perform instance-level administrative operations on your behalf; you *could* reset the password and login as this account to grant superuser privileges, but I do not recommend doing so as this is likely to break other managed functions.

---

## Worked example

The default set of roles present in a newly-created database cluster is as follows:

```
                                        List of roles
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |      Member of
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------
 cloudsqladmin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 cloudsqlagent     | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqlreplica   | Replication                                                | {}
 cloudsqlsuperuser | Create role, Create DB                                     | {}
 postgres          | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
```

Moreover, new databases created using the "Databases" tab in the Cloud Console have ownership assigned, by default, to the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role. (As shown in the above role listing, the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role is inherited by the `postgres` user.)

```
                                  List of databases
  Name  |       Owner       | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | Access privileges
--------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------
 testdb | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8     | en_US.UTF8 | en_US.UTF8 |
```

Accordingly, members of the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role will have permissions to create objects in the database by default. However, when doing so, they will by default have their owner set to the user which created them, rather than the parent role:

```
testdb=> CREATE TABLE sometable (id SERIAL NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=> \dt sometable
           List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------+-------+----------
 public | sometable | table | testuser
```

If we call `SET ROLE cloudsqlsuperuser` before creating our table, the owner will now default to the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role, which will allow `postgres` and other members of the role the default permissions assigned to the role by default:

You can also use triggers and other approaches to [set the role automatically](https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/) on table creation.

```
testdb=> SET ROLE cloudsqlsuperuser;
SET
testdb=> CREATE TABLE anothertable (id SERIAL NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=> \dt anothertable;
                 List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |       Owner
--------+--------------+-------+-------------------
 public | anothertable | table | cloudsqlsuperuser
(1 row)
```

For production usage, as noted in the "Alternatives" section, I recommend using a dedicated role rather than the built-in `cloudsqlsuperuser` role.

Comment: Thank you so much! I 'll try your solution... If I use your first solution I receive this error : ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers ... How can I solve it?

Comment: Ah of course, you won't be able to do that as `postgres` itself is not a superuser, and you don't have access to any user which is. (You must be a superuser to assign superuser rights, and the only user in Cloud SQL which is such a user is cloudsqladmin, which you should ideally not reset the password for.)

Comment: I try also your second alternative but it doesn't work... proxyuser don't has the permission...

Comment: Are you trying to create a new role? Which user are you trying to create the role as?