# Why role cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles, sql-grant, sql-revoke

Database "mydb" is owned by role "mydb_owner".

User "currentuser"  tries to delete role "roletodelete" from this database using

```
revoke all on all tables in schema public,firma1 from "roletodelete" cascade;
revoke all on all sequences in schema public,firma1 from "roletodelete" cascade;
revoke all on database mydb from "roletodelete" cascade;
revoke all on all functions in schema public,firma1 from "roletodelete" cascade;
revoke all on schema public,firma1 from "roletodelete" cascade;
revoke mydb_owner from "roletodelete" cascade;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public,firma1 revoke all ON TABLES from "roletodelete";
GRANT "roletodelete" TO "currentuser";
reassign owned by "roletodelete" to mydb_owner;
drop owned by "roletodelete";
drop role "roletodelete";
```

I ran it as superuser and got

```
    ERROR: role "roletodelete" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role currentuser in schema public
privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role currentuser schema firma1
```

How to create script which  is guaranteed to delete role ?

This script already contains:

```
revoke all on schema public,firma1 from "roletodelete" cascade;
```

Why postgres complains that privileges for schema public depend on this role if they are revoked ?
How to fix this?

There are lot of questions and answers about this like:

[Cannot drop PostgreSQL role. Error: `cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256454/cannot-drop-postgresql-role-error-cannot-be-dropped-because-some-objects-depe)

[PostgreSQL - how to quickly drop a user with existing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023583/postgresql-how-to-quickly-drop-a-user-with-existing-privileges)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155332/find-objects-linked-to-a-postgresql-role

I put recommendations from them to deletion script above but problem persists.

Comment: Scipt in question already contains `reassign owned by "roletodelete" to mydb_owner`  . How to try it more?

Comment: Then maybe that role owns objects in another database

Comment: It should not have. It was created and used in this database only. But there are total 30 databases, maybe it is used by mistake.  How to check this ? Maybe some query on common system tables can show where role is still used ?

Comment: I ran it as superuser and got more details `DETAIL:  privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role someotherrole in schema public
privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role someotherrole in schema firma1`   How to drop them also ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Encountered the same problem, and managed to solve it using the following SQL

This should remove all the rights before removing the user:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY <user> TO <other-user>;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON ROUTINES FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON TYPES FROM <user>;

REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE GRANT OPTION FOR ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL ROUTINES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ROUTINES FROM <user>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TYPES FROM <user>;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL ROUTINES IN SCHEMA <schema> FROM <user>;

DROP ROLE <user>;
```

This first assigns all database objects to another user, revokes all the privileges, including default privileges, before finally dropping the role itself.

Comment: Why you dont use `drop owned by <user>` ?  Your code is required only if user has privileges in other database to clear it before dropping since drop owned by drops only in current database.

Comment: If you happen to forget to `REASSIGN` before you `DROP`, this will lead to potential catastrophic data loss. being explicit using `REVOKE` will prevent this issue.

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me out of quite a few answers, thank you