# PostgreSQL: role is not permitted to log in

Tags: database, postgresql, authentication, permissions, roles

I have trouble connecting to my own postgres db on a local server.
I googled some similar problems and came up with this manual
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/postgresql.html

so:

`pg_hba.conf` says:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

then I create a user and assign a password for it:

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE asunotest;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# ALTER ROLE asunotest WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '1234';
ALTER ROLE
```

but it doesn't let me in:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U asunotest
Password for user asunotest: 1234
psql: FATAL:  role "asunotest" is not permitted to log in
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 495, accepted):

The role you have created is not allowed to log in.  You have to give the role permission to log in.

One way to do this is to log in as the `postgres` user and update the role:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Once you are logged in, type:

```
ALTER ROLE "asunotest" WITH LOGIN;
```

Here's the documentation 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterrole.html

Comment: As I can't `psql`, how can I ALTER ROLE?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai you should enter as a postgres user ( sudo -u postgres psql postgres )

Comment: For me on PeppermintOS the first command is "sudo -u postgres psql".

Answer (score 26):

```
CREATE ROLE blog WITH
  LOGIN
  SUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  CREATEDB
  CREATEROLE
  REPLICATION;

COMMENT ON ROLE blog IS 'Test';
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using pgadmin4**  :

1. Select roles in side menu
2. Select properties in dashboard.
3. Click Edit and select privileges

Now there you can enable or disable login, roles and other options

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can alter the existing user(role) `john` to have `LOGIN` attribute with [ALTER ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-alterrole.html) or [ALTER USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH LOGIN;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER USER john WITH LOGIN;
```

*Memos:

- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).
- You can omit `WITH` which is optional.
- [ALTER GROUP statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-altergroup.html) cannot alter an existing user(role) to have `LOGIN` attribute.

And, you can create the user(role) `john` with the password `apple` using [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html), [CREATE GROUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creategroup.html) or [CREATE USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html)  statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE GROUP john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE USER john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'apple';
```

*Memos:

- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).
- You can omit `WITH` which is optional.
- You must use `''` for `PASSWORD` instead of `""` otherwise there is error.
- By default, `CREATE USER` without `LOGIN` can still have `LOGIN` attribute implicitly.
- By default, PostgreSQL needs a password so you should set `PASSWORD`.

In addition, if you want to drop the superuser `john`, first, run these SQL below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023583/how-to-quickly-drop-a-user-with-existing-privileges/77299812#77299812) explains how to drop a user(role) properly:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY john TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY john;
```

Finally, you can drop the superuser `john` with [DROP ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droprole.html), [DROP GROUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropgroup.html) or [DROP USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropuser.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
DROP ROLE john;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP GROUP john;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP USER john;
```

Answer (score -8):

try to run

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
ALTER ROLE 'dbname'
```