# psql "role is not permitted to login" & "could not connect to server"

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I cloned a project i did on cloud9 IDE on my computer. This project is on rails and use Heroku & postgresql.

I want to launch it from my computer, i did everything needed to launch the project like install libs, bundle install, install postgresql etc...

But it seems i missed something for postgresql. I encounter 2 issues

The first one, I can't launch psql directly from my bash like i do on Cloud9. I must do :

```
sudo -i -u postgres //it open something like a new bash
psql //then psql is launch
```

I wish to be able to type only psql but it display

```
role tellimi is not permitted to log in
```

I tried to create role ([PostgreSQL: role is not permitted to log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254786/postgresql-role-is-not-permitted-to-log-in)) but the message became

```
database tellimi does not exist
```

but tellimi is my username, not a database

Then i wanted to check my database on salesforce so i add the url in a new env variable $DTABASE_URL but when i do

```
psql $DATABASE_URL
```

it display

> psql: could not connect to server: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente
>       Is the server running on host "ec2-54-247-125-202.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (54.247.125.202) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

So how to set-up correctly postgresql to answer those 2 problems?

Comment: what is your database name?.. try `psql -U postgres -d postgres`

Comment: I didn't create one localy. My database is on Salesforce servers and connected to my app with Heroku connect. It take $DATABASE_URL variable to found the DB. psql -U postgres -d postgres work

Comment: ah! I missed heroku. and what you see after `heroku pg:psql` ?..

Comment: same error like 'psql $DATABASE_URL' : "psql: could not connect to the server.......... accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: then the value of `$DATABASE_URL` is bad :)

Comment: I copied and pasted it from c9 env where it worked. just in case it was a wrong value i just copied the variable from my heroku dashboard settings and it still fail

Comment: I guess this part of error message "accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" is a part of the solution

Comment: well, connection can be firewalled for `54.247.125.202` from ne IP and allowed from the other...

Comment: I'm not at all good with Ip, Port etc. have you got any doc or something to help me?

Comment: `vao@ud64:/t/sq$ psql -h 54.247.125.202 -p 5432 -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "159.134.255.230", user "postgres", database "t", SSL off
` I tried to reach your db myself. It is not firewalled for me. try `ping www.google.com` from that machine (where you get error)

Comment: No problem when i ping google. Rails port is 3000, postgres error message talk about 5432. can it be the cause ?

Comment: I tell you - it allows me to reach your db. port and ip are ok