# Can not login to Postgres DB as new user

Tags: postgresql

I have installed Foreman via foreman-installer (that pack included Postgres DB 9.5). Now i want to create new user + new database for Zabbix, however it seems that i am doing something wrong. The image shows what commands i typed. The new user is created succesfully but i can't login as it to database. Could someone help me and explain where is the problem?

EDIT: I've added option that was suggested in another thread (WITH LOGIN) but it didn't help me:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: role is not permitted to log in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254786/postgresql-role-is-not-permitted-to-log-in)

Comment: paste the contents of your pg_hba

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge).

In summary, "peer authentication" means postgres checked the username of the UNIX user (which is not `zabbix`), and ignored your `-U` option. Instead, you want to use "password authentication", which you can configure in your `pg_hba.conf` file. Check the link for instructions how to do that.